# The connection was not closed. The connection's current state is open.C#

Tags: c#

I am practicing my C# programming skill, I am relatively new, I am trying to create a software that helps my father to keep track with his document, I am doing quite well but run into this problem.

When i run the code, it works fine, and when I input some information to my textbox, let's say I input 123 as the ID, and it shows "Since this is already a primary key, and the ID already existed, choose something else", so I retype my ID as 1234 for testing purposes, and I got this error "The connection was not closed. The connection's current state is open" I do have con.Open() and con.Close(), but I still can not fix the problem, here is my code, if anyone can help, thank you so much:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
namespace Documents
{
    public partial class hoadonKT : Form
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.HoaDonKetThucConnection);
        SqlCommand cmd;
        SqlDataAdapter da;
        DataTable dt;
        public hoadonKT()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void Label1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // save button
            if (textBox1.Text == "" && textBox2.Text == "")
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Hay dien du thong tin can thiet");
            }
            else
            {
                try
                {
                    con.Open();
                    cmd = new SqlCommand(@"INSERT INTO [dbo].[KTHoaDon]
                                        ([MaDon],[TenDon])
                    VALUES

                    ('"+textBox1.Text+"','"+textBox2.Text+"')",con);
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    con.Close();
                    MessageBox.Show("Du Lieu Da Duoc Luu Tru");
                    fillGrid();

                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                }
            }
        }

        public void fillGrid()
        {
            // fill datagridview from datatable
            con.Open();
            da = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from KTHoaDon order by MaDon asc", con);
            con.Close();
            SqlCommandBuilder cd = new SqlCommandBuilder(da);
            dt = new DataTable();
            da.Fill(dt);
            dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
        }

        private void Button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void HoadonKT_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            fillGrid();

        }

        int i;
        private void DataGridView1_CellDoubleClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
            i = e.RowIndex;
            DataGridViewRow row = dataGridView1.Rows[i];
            textBox1.Text = row.Cells[0].Value.ToString();
            textBox2.Text = row.Cells[1].Value.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That's why you should always use the [using](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-statement) statements.

Comment: I don't quite understand, can you elaborate a little more? Thank you for your answer

Comment: Do not force the user to "invent" an ID. Create an auto-ID Column and leave it out when inserting. The DB will create an ID for you. You still have other issues, but this is the main one for this question, I think.

Comment: What Salah means is: You do not close the connection after you try to insert and an exception occurrs. Using the `using` statement prevents this (follow his link).

Answer (score 1):

try this code.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
namespace Documents
{
    public partial class hoadonKT : Form
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.HoaDonKetThucConnection);
        SqlCommand cmd;
        SqlDataAdapter da;
        DataTable dt;
        public hoadonKT()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // save button
            if (textBox1.Text == "" && textBox2.Text == "")
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Hay dien du thong tin can thiet");
            }
            else
            {
                try
                {
                    string queryText = "INSERT INTO [dbo].[KTHoaDon] ([MaDon],[TenDon]) VALUES(@MaDon,@TenDon)";
                    using (cmd = new SqlCommand(queryText, con))
                    {
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("MaDon", textBox1.Text);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("TenDon", textBox2.Text);

                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    }
                    MessageBox.Show("Du Lieu Da Duoc Luu Tru");

                    fillGrid();

                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                }
            }
        }

        public void fillGrid()
        {
            dt = new DataTable();
            // fill datagridview from datatable
            using (da = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from KTHoaDon order by MaDon asc", con))
            {                                
                da.Fill(dt);
            }
            dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
        }

        private void HoadonKT_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            con.Open();
            fillGrid();
        }

        private void HoadonKT_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {
            con.Close();
        }

        int i;
        private void DataGridView1_CellDoubleClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
            i = e.RowIndex;
            DataGridViewRow row = dataGridView1.Rows[i];
            textBox1.Text = row.Cells[0].Value.ToString();
            textBox2.Text = row.Cells[1].Value.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```